# Azure KeyVault Access Policy exception when creating service fabric cluster with PowerShell using New-AzureRmServiceFabricCluster

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to create an Azure Service Fabric cluster using PowerShell script described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/scripts/service-fabric-powershell-create-secure-cluster-cert

The script creates everything (including Key Vault) in one step by calling New-AzureRmServiceFabricCluster command.

After setting the variables and running the script in PowerShell I am getting this warning and then exception:

```
WARNING: Access policy is not set. No user or application have access permission to use this vault. Please use Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy to set a
ccess policies.
New-AzureRmServiceFabricCluster : 10:00:24 AM - System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> 
Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Models.KeyVaultErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient.<CreateCertificateWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__84.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClientExtensions.<CreateCertificateAsync>d__68.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ServiceFabric.Commands.ServiceFabricClusterCertificateCmdlet.CreateSelfSignedCertificate(String subjectName, String 
keyVaultUrl, String& thumbprint, CertificateBundle& certificateBundle, String& outputFilePath)
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Models.KeyVaultErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient.<CreateCertificateWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__84.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClientExtensions.<CreateCertificateAsync>d__68.MoveNext()<---
At C:\GitVSTS\BusinessPlatform\Scripts\Create_SF_Secure_Cluster.ps1:50 char:1
+ New-AzureRmServiceFabricCluster -Name $clustername -ResourceGroupName ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmServiceFabricCluster], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ServiceFabric.Commands.NewAzureRmServiceFabricCluster

New-AzureRmServiceFabricCluster : One or more errors occurred.
At C:\GitVSTS\BusinessPlatform\Scripts\Create_SF_Secure_Cluster.ps1:50 char:1
+ New-AzureRmServiceFabricCluster -Name $clustername -ResourceGroupName ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmServiceFabricCluster], AggregateException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ServiceFabric.Commands.NewAzureRmServiceFabricCluster
```

In the portal when browsing the resource group I can see the KeyVault actually created, though nothing else.

This is really strange because I don't have a chance to setup access policy before the Key Vault is created.

I tried creating the Access Policy on the created KeyVault and ran the script again - the same error.

I am sure that I am the owner of the subscription and have all admin rights.
Does anybody know what's going on here?

Comment: is it using a precreated KV? if yes - you need to grant yourself appropriate permissions to deploy using that KV

Comment: Can you also add your powershell script to the Question

Comment: Did you check 'enable template deployment' for the key vault? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/key-vault-setup

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/910

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally figured this out.

This happened because I have two Azure subscriptions under different user accounts, and I have previously run Azure PowerShell scripts for both of them. PowerShell remembered my sessions and while creating cluster somehow mixed them up, applying wrong credentials.

The fix to that is to cleanup PowerShell sessions:

```
Clear-AzureRmContext -Scope CurrentUser
```

This fixed it for me.